# add copyright notice and if it is deleted or changed stop website from loading

Tags: javascript, php, html, hosting

title shows it all!
I want to add a copyright notice to one my friend website.[i am making a website for him]. and i want to protect my copyright.
for example:- if i am writing "this website is created and edited by sidhant sood"
and if this data is changed or deleted, the website should not open.

what i have thought so far:-

i have my own hosting and in any way if i can link his website to require one of the file present at my hosting.

in this way i can check hi website anytime. if there is correct copyright i will do nothing but if there is something wrong, i will delete the file from my hosting and website should not open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "this website is created and edited by sidhant sood" and if this data
>   is changed or deleted, the website should not open.

The bottom line is that all HTML, CSS and JavaScript executes on the client and there is nothing you can do to protect that code from users seeing it and changing their local copies of it.

As for your friend who will own and control the site's source code, if someone changes your copyright notice (presumably your friend), what makes you think that they won't remove the JavaScript that checks to see if that is there?

In the end, if someone controls the source code and can remove your copyright, then they can also remove the code that enforces that the copyright is there.

Comment: what if i make it require some php from my hosting and if i see there is an edited copyright i will delete the php file on my hosting and the website will not open??

Comment: Again, anyone who controls the source code (your friend) could simply remove that .php call.

Comment: yes i thought that too, i want to make it in that way that this php will also load something on his site which is neccesory for him and if he removes that php call his website will not open

Comment: plz you can help in adding a require call to that php which is present on my hosting

Comment: And (again), if he controls the source code, he can just remove the part that makes the page not open. You simply cannot do this in any meaningful way.

Comment: No. Your friend controls the hosting. So they can remove it at any time.

Comment: if i cant do that may be i can create a php file which can delete any file. in this way i will keep this file in a folder secretly and if see a change of copyright i will run this file it will delete a necessory file and website will not open

Comment: I've tried to be as clear as I can. If you do not control the source code, then there is absolutely nothing you can do. This is the nature of how the web works.

Comment: thanks for your helping! i had created a file which can delete something on hosting. this will do my work. and plz upvote this questoin it is graving my reputation. plz

Comment: @SidhantSood But, if you don't control the hosting, then your file can be deleted, so no, that's not a solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But I'm doing it secretly. Maybe he will never know about this file among thousands of other files.I know this is not a solution, But I have this only choice. This question is open, You can help me whenever you have a better option.

Comment: @SidhantSood *" Maybe he will never know about this..."* And, maybe he'll find out immediately. The real question is simply, why do you need to do this? This is an issue that is solved by a business arrangement and follow up on your part to ensure that the disclaimer stays where it should be. If not, the issue is solved via a phone call, not code.